# Create process suspend and UAC

Tags: c++, windows

I have an inyector application to map a remote DLL into another process. The process i am trying to insert into have its own manifest and require admin privileges. I am trying to use CreateProcess since i can create the process in a suspended state, do my mapping into remote memory and then resume it.

Now according to MS i can use ShellExecute with the runas verb but this will start running the process right away. Is there any method to request the user to run the process as admin and at the same time creating the process in a suspended state?.

Comment: If your process doesn't have admin privilege, then it won't be able to modify the elevated process anyway.  Either configure your program to require elevation, or launch an elevated subprocess to do the work on your behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target executable has a UAC manifest that specifies `requiresAdminstrator` then you don't need to do anything extra. Just use `CreateProcess()` normally and let the OS deal with the elevation for you.  Elevation will be applied to the new process before `CreateProcess()` returns control back to you.

You only need to elevate manually if the target executable DOES NOT have a UAC manifest that forces elevation.  In which case, you can use something like [`CreateProcessElevated()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) if you do not want to use `ShellExecute/Ex()`.

Comment: Then its Visual studio problem maybe, because i am debugging my project in VS and CreateProcess is returning that i dont have enough privileges.

Comment: That makes me think you are not using it correctly. Please show your actual code. You do not need special privileges to create a new process. If the calling process is not running as an admin, UAC will prompt the user for full credentials. If the calling processing is running as an admin, UAC will simply prompt for permission instead. Either way, UAC handles those details tranparently, the calling process does not need to know or care about them. All it cares about is that a new process is created.

Comment: Well nevermind it was Visual Studio that it wasnt running on administrative level, now everything is ok, thanks for thelp

Comment: This is wrong.  The `CreateProcess` function does not perform elevation, if the existing credentials are not adequate for the target executable then `CreateProcess` will fail.